# How to resolve Generic Interface by a Singleton instance without providing separate concrete implementations

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, factory, simple-injector

I have a class **MyBusiness** that I register with **SimpleInjector**

```
container.RegisterSingleton<MyBusiness>(() => new MyBusiness(Konstants.ConnectionString));
```

now MyBusiness implements an interface **IRepositoryProvider** which is like this

```
public interface IRepositoryProvider{
  IReader<Entity> Get<Entity>();
  IWriter<Entity> Writer<Entity>();
}
```

**IReader** and **IWriter** both inherit **IDisposable** and Entity is some database entity, a POCO class if you will, which may be quite many (assume more than 50 entities in the app generated by some tool). MyBusiness provides the implementations of **IReader<>** and **IWriter<>** for any entity that is passed as Generic parameter, I do not provide implementation for any **IReader<>**, **IWriter<>**

so in code they are used like:

```
var biz = container.GetInstance<MyBusiness>();
using(var users = biz.Get<User>()){
...

}
```

Due to the above I cannot use **IReader<>** and **IWriter<>** in constructor injection.

```
public class MyUserController:Controller{
   public MyUserController(IReader<User> arg){
   }
   // other functionality
}
```

Can the calls for **IReader IWriter** above be reduced to this

```
var users = container.GetInstance<IReader<User>>());
```

so that I can easily use the **IReader<>** and **IWriter<>** implementations as dependency injections?

Answer (score 3):

> IReader and IWriter both implement IDisposable

Let's start with this: Abstractions should in general *not* implement `IDisposable`. By doing so you are leaking implementation details through the abstraction. This means you are violating the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), which states:

> *Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.*

You are leaking implementation details, because it's typically unlikely that *all* implementations of that abstraction have resources they need to dispose. For instance:

- You are likely to have mock or fake implementations that don't require disposal.
- If you create a decorators or interceptor for such abstraction, they typically not have any resources they need to dispose.

Still, since the client expects dispose to actually dispose 'the real thing', those decorators and other implementations are forced to delegate the call through to any wrapped call.

But what if the decorator does get an instance injected through constructor injection. Does it know how whether or not that dependency can be disposed or not? Perhaps it has a long lifestyle and disposing it actually breaks the system.

The solution is to remove `IDisposable` from the abstraction. This typically makes your application code much simpler, because the client code is not able to call `Dispose` anymore. This means less code to test, and less things to go wrong (because someone called dispose while he shouldn't).

This does mean however, that we should move the responsibility of disposing that instance, and this is typically what Dependency Injection gives us. It gives us a central place in the application (called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)) that exactly knows when to dispose what.

Typically, when using a DI Container, the solution is to register such type with a Scoped lifestyle. This means that the instance lives for a certain amount of time. It is than the DI Container how is in control of calling `Dispose` on your behalf, once the class's lifetime ends.

With Simple Injector, this is typically done as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IReader<>), typeof(ReaderImpl<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

This means that you can safely inject `IReader<User>` in the `MyUserController`, without the `MyUserController` having to worry about disposal and Simple Injector will dispose the `ReaderImpl<User>` at the end of the web request.

When you need to return `IReader<T>` implementations from a factory-like method as `IRepositoryProvider.Get<T>`, you will have to create an implementation that wraps the `Container` instance. This means that the `IRepositoryProvider` implementation does the following:

```
container.GetInstance<IReader<User>>());
```

In other words, this is exactly the code you described.

But be warned, prevent having *any* application code from taking a dependency on the Container. That's an commonly known anti-pattern called [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Instead, move the `IRepositoryProvider` *implementation* into your Composition Root.

Comment: but then i added these 2 registrations: con.Register<IDataRepository>(()=> container.GetInstance<MyBusiness>().Repository, Lifestyle.Transient);
            container.Register(typeof(IReader<>), () => container.GetInstance<IDataRepository>().Get<???>());  how do i specify the entities =>???

Comment: @SimpleFellow: You can't specify a lambda for an open-generic type. But you should turn it around. Don't forward the creation of `IReader<T>` to `MyBusiness`, but let the container create `IReader<T>` and have `MyBusiness` resolve it from the container (or get it injected). In that case you can make the registration as follows: `container.Register(typeof(IReader<>), typeof(ReaderImpl<>))`.

Comment: but how do i do that? Mybusiness exposes functions that are generic. MyBusiness is registered as singleton. there is no IReaderImpl. how do I do that? Sorry I'm not really an expert on this.

Comment: how can Simple injector resolve container.GetInstance<IReader<User>>();

Comment: What do you mean by there is now reader implementation? There has to be.

Comment: it's inside the 3rd party dll, which i cannot create. as it has private constructor i believe.

Comment: In that case you will manually have to make 40 registrations. One for each entity.

Comment: is it possible that i create them myself but register them as IDisposable in simple injector?

Comment: You want Simple Injector to dispose them? You can either register them as Scoped, or call `Scope.RegisterForDisposal` an the active scope to make sure they are disposed when the Scope is disposed.